# html to php change

Tags: php

if i change the extension of html file as .php means it will make any changes..?

Comment: Yes - your html file will have a different extension.

Answer (score 10):

The effect of changing a `.html` extension to `.php` depends on the web server configuration; if the server is configured with PHP installed and associated with `.php` files, then the PHP preprocessor will be run against the file before the HTML is printed. In the case of a standard HTML file with no extras, this will make no obvious difference, although client-side caching may behave differently, and any incoming links will of course be broken. There's also a slight performance penalty.

If PHP isn't installed, or hasn't been configured to handle `.php` files (some PHP 5 configurations are set for `.php5`) then the web server will usually spit out the raw text of the file, which may or may not be treated as HTML by the browser.

Answer (score 5):

No. It will just mean the page goes through the PHP interpreter rather than being directly served (assuming the PHP interpreter actually exists and is configured properly with your server).